Как правильно обращаться к переменным в модуле формы обработки?
Не могу разобраться как в модуле обращаться к реквизитам! У меня есть иерархический справочник, добавляю в реквизит обьекта обработки, Справочник.Ссылка, и после могу пользоваться только одним реквизитом, а до остальных достучаться не получается
Понимаю что вопрос элементарный


А что в целом вам нужно сделать? На какой именно реквизит у вас ругается?

По заданию нужно вычислить факториалы чисел, в зависимости с какими ограниччениями вводишь

На какую переменную ругается? Покажите текст ошибки.

При вводе
ЧислоРасчета = Элементы.РеквизитОбработкиВидРасчетов;
Сообщить(ЧислоРасчета);
затем открытия предприятия
ругается на меня что:  Поле обьекта не обнаруженр (ВидРасчетоав)

Реквизит "ВидРасчетов" у вас является реквизитом справочника "Ограничения". У обработки вы добавили реквизит "РеквизитОбработки" (Тип "СправочникСсылка.Ограничения"). В этом реквизите ("РеквизитОбработки") будет хранится ссылка на справочник. Чтобы через нее получить реквизиты самого справочника, достаточно просто обратиться через точку:
ЧислоРасчета = Объект.РеквизитОбработки.ВидРасчетов;
Обращение к данным по ссылке через точку называется "разыменование".

Пока что не могу понять, что вы в целом хотите в этой обработке делать: что выбирать, что рассчитывать и т.п.

https://ibb.co/VmTyq6b вот мое тестовое задание. Я разобрался со справочниками и согласно заданию в обработке создал форму. Но у меня не получается в модуле обработки работать с переменными. Я понимаю как запрограммировать но не знаю как достать переменные.
В приложении пользователь вводит данные и нажимает рассчитать.

Судя по всему, для выбора вида расчетов вам нужно создать отдельный реквизит (обработки или на самой форме), и вывести его в элементы, а не через справочник.

По невнимательности код писал &наКлиенте, переписал на &наСервере все сработало
